# Question about SNPs selection in Mendelian randomisation for mediation analysis

Tags: mediation, mendelianrandomization

I recently read the paper entitled "Mendelian randomisation for mediation analysis: current methods and challenges for implementation". https://doi.org/10.1007/s10654-021-00757-1
I am still confused about the selection of SNPs in mutivariable (MVMR) and two-step MR when apply them to mediation analysis.
For example, if my exposure is 'BMI', mediator is 'fasting glucose level' and the outcome is 'pancreatic cancer risk'. How do I choose the SNPs as instruments in MVMR and two-step MR, respectively?
My current understanding is, in MVMR, the first step would be a univariable MR using all the SNPs significantly associated with BMI to estimate the total effect of BMI on the outcome; the second step would be a MVMR (using the SNPs associated with both BMI and fasting glucose level) to estimate the direct effect of BMI on the outcome which is independent of the mediator.

In two-step MR, I assume the first step would be the same? but I am not sure about what SNPs to choose in the second step, when estimating the effect of the exposure on the mediator, and the effect of the mediator on the outcome, respectively.
In addition, I would use individual-level data in my analysis.